# Parse Youtube Links

Tags: java, regex, youtube

I'm struggling with the following problem. I need all youtube links of a html content (in a string) that do not   start with a single quote. I need the regex in Java. I already have the following regex, but it doesn't work:

```
[^\'].*(https\\:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com\\/[a-z,A-Z,0-9,\\?\\=\\&\\%\\!]*)
```

The Regex should match:

- `"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk"`
- `" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk"`
- `"asd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk asd"`

The Regex should not match:

- `"'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk"`
- (optional) `"aaaahttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk"`
- (optional) `"123https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk"`

Can anybody help me?

Regards
Tronje

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some examples which must be accepted or regected

Comment: Don't put commas inside the square brackets, unless you intend to match a comma.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I edited the post with some matching and not matching examples. thank you for the input.

Comment: @user3165309 but `"asd https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyWu7dVuRfk asd"` isnt a valid url

Comment: @nu11p01n73R it should only match the url part of it

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex

```
"\w*\s*\bhttps:\/\/www\.youtube\.com.*"$
```

See how the regex matches at http://regex101.com/r/nN1cQ6/1

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work with java regex   "\\w*\\s*\\bhttps:\\/\\/www\\.youtube\\.com.*"$